# Admin not permitted to modify or delete the entire System keychain from macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, keychain, macos-sierra

I want to delete 2 items from my System keychain, but I'm not allowed
even when logged in as an admin.

Wiping the entire keychain does not work either: `sudo rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Keychains/System.keychain`

=> **Operation not permitted**

```
ls -l "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  84772 Dec 22 19:14 /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Keychains/System.keychain
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: My monitor broke too. I got the Apple service team to fix it while they changed the monitor. Don't know what they did. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To delete the whole keychain try this. You can use terminal but it will probably be easier in Finder for this one. Open finder. Click the Go menu up top. While holding the click press the option key to reveal the hidden user library. Select library. Select the Keychain directory. Delete the crazy title directory with all the gibberish. Log out and log back in.

If you are signed into the iCloud keychain I might suggest signing out of that first under System Preferences -> iCloud. However, the desired deletions may return if and when you reconnect to the iCloud keychain.